# Webhook for users checkins on facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to add a webhook for tagged_places for users which authorized my app. It's possible?

I trying to use subscriptions as described here for checkins:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/

But I wasn't receiving any POST request, just the GET request for make the subscription.

Does anyone have any ideia how do that?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your question because I want to do pretty much the same thing. From what I have read so far it isn't possible, since the `tagged_places` field [is not listed as a field which supports webhooks](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/#subscribefields).